# hive count and count distinct not correct

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table in Hive that has 20 columns and I want to count unique records and all records per hour.

Table looks like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1(
  log_date string, 
  advertiser_creatives_id string, 
  cookieID string, 
) 
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION "/day1orc"
tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB");
```

And my query like this:

```
SELECT Hour(log_date), 
       Count(DISTINCT cookieid) AS UNIQUE, 
       Count(1)                 AS impressions 
FROM   test1 
GROUP  BY Hour(log_date);
```

But the results are not correct. I have about 70 million entries and when I do a sum of impressions I only get like 8 million so I suspect the distinct takes too many columns in account.

So how can I fix this so that I get the correct amount of impressions?

** Extra information **

`hive.vectorized.execution.enabled` is undefined so it is not active.

The same query in TEXT format returns even less rows (about 2.7 million)

Result of `COUNT(*)`: 70643229

Result of `COUNT(cookieID)`: 70643229

Result of `COUNT(DISTINCT cookieID)`: 1440195

Cheers

Comment: Hive 0.11 or Hive 0.12 ? Is it possible to share a data file that reproes the problem?

Comment: Hive 0.12 and the data isn't mine to share but the sum of it all doesn't add up. 70 million records but when I count it I only get 8 million.

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAIN for the query? You did not enable vectorization by any chance (`set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true;`), did you?

Comment: also, can you post check `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(cookieID)`. Also, if possible, can you try with the same data in any other format (not ORC), and post back the discrepancies, if any?

Comment: added extra info in my post :)

Comment: Can you post the full query output? Are you saying the impressions column sums to 8m or the UNIQUE column sums to 8m? The thing you said about DISTINCT interfering with the impressions column has got me confused, since the calculations are independent.

Comment: The sum of the impressions column is 8 million where I expected it to be 70 million. My guess was that the distinct also included another column and messed up the impressions aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

I have an example,may be useful for you.I think you "row format delimited fields terminated by" has some problems .
I have a text,seperate by "\t",like below:

```
id    date      value
1   01-01-2014  10
1   03-01-2014  05
1   07-01-2014  40
1   05-01-2014  20
2   05-01-2014  10
```

but I only create a table have 2 columns, like below:

```
use tmp ;
create table sw_test(id string,td string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' ;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hadoop/b.txt' INTO TABLE sw_test;
```

How do you think the result of "select td from sw_test ;"

NOT

```
td
01-01-2014  10
03-01-2014  05
07-01-2014  40
05-01-2014  20
05-01-2014  10
```

BUT

```
td
01-01-2014
03-01-2014
07-01-2014
05-01-2014
05-01-2014
```

So,I think you cookie contains some special column include your defined seperator.
I hope this can help you .
good luck!